Unable to import tensorflow on macos python3.9
Recently received a new laptop (MacBook Air, M3, 2024) and after installing python (through the python website https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/) and tensorflow (via pip install tensorflow) I am unable to import or use tensorflow.
This appears to be unique to tensorflow since I do not receive any issues when installing and importing other packages e.g. torch, numpy, pandas, polas, etc.
When importing tensorflow via the terminal e.g. via entering the following into terminal:
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

or by initialising python then importing;
python
import tensorflow

I get a popup saying "Python quit unexpectedly." with following error message in the terminal:

zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python

Similarly, when attempting to run code in VScode my script simply makes no progress (no errors thrown and VScode does not freeze, it just looks like it's running indefinitely). I left it to run for over an hour before stopping the code manually.
System:
Chip: Apple M3
macos: 14.4.1 (23E224)
Python version:
python3 --version
Python 3.9.13

pip --version
pip 24.0 from venv-path/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

I have tried installing multiple versions of tensorflow on different environments, including tensorflow==2.16.1, 2.15.1, 2.14.1, yet run into the same issues. Preferably I would like to be using 2.16.1.
I searched online for solutions but most seem to point to downgrading to / using Python3.8, which I do not wish to do since I would like to run on the same environment as my team and also I am unsure this will fix the problem, or appear tailored to issues with MacBook M1.
I tried creating a new virtual environment, upgrading pip, and installing tensorflow (without explicitly installing any other packages) and ran into the same issue.
I tried pip install tensorflow-macos but get the following (presumably because I'm using Python3.9?):
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos

I tried the following guide to installing macos version of tensorflow with conda but ended up running into issues, possibly because this is for Mac M1, possibly because I am not familiar with conda.
https://github.com/deganza/Install-TensorFlow-on-Mac-M1-GPU/blob/main/Install-TensorFlow-on-Mac-M1-GPU.ipynb
When following the conda guide I was unable to run the following line:
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
But I can unsure what error message I got here.
UPDATE - managed to solve the issue myself using homebrew and miniforge. Guide below.
https://medium.com/@kakadechaitanya77/initializing-tensorflow-environment-on-m3-m3-pro-and-m3-max-macbook-pros-6fb9a7b2e86a
